# Call an array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have my array in PHP like this:

```
$countryList = array (
    array( // Asia
        continent => 'Asia', 
        country   => array('Japan', 'China')
    ),
    array( // Europe
        continent => 'Europe', 
        country   => array('Spain', 'France', 'Italy')
    )
);
```

How can I call this array (`$countryList`) to ask what is the value of `country` if the `continent` is 'Asia' ?

I would like to have something like:

```
$country = 'Japan, China';
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You  could make it so that the base index of the arrays are the continent names. E. G. `$countryList =array('europe'=>array('Spain', 'France'),' asia'=>array()) ; would make it easier to get to the other data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$countryList = array (
    array( // Asia
        'continent' => 'Asia', 
        'country'   => array('Japan', 'China')
    ),
    array( // Europe
        'continent' => 'Europe', 
        'country'   => array('Spain', 'France', 'Italy')
    )
);

$continent = 'Asia';

foreach($countryList as $c)
  if ($c['continent'] == $continent)
  {
      echo join(', ', $c['country']);
      break;
  }
```

But it is better and easier to use associative arrays.

```
$countryList = array (
    'Asia'   => array('Japan', 'China'),
    'Europe' => array('Spain', 'France', 'Italy')
);

$continent = 'Asia';

echo isset($countryList[$continent]) ?
         join(', ', $countryList[$continent]) :
         'No such continent';
```

The last `echo` has an equivalent of the `if` .. `then` .. structure and checks whether the element with corresponding key exists in the array.

Comment: I'm on mobile, but would pop's array search key function work?

Comment: @Jhecht nope, those are not the keys.

Comment: Array search return the corresponding key, what I meant to say. Autocorrect.  Then again that won't work either because of the state of his array.

Comment: @Jhecht `isset` is much better and faster than search of the keys.

Answer (score 0):

You should just change the way the data is structured, to something like this:

```
$countryList = array(
    'Asia'   => array('Japan, China'),
    'Europe' => array('Spain', 'France', 'Italy'),
);
```

That way, instead of having to search the array, you can just access it directly:

```
$region = 'Europe';
$countries = implode(', ', $countryList[$region]);
echo "Europe countries: {$countries}.";
```

Answer (score -2):

You can implode the array of this way

```
$country = implode(', ', countryList['Asia']);
```

Greetings

Comment: Given the original question this would not work since `Asia` is not a valid index for that array declaration. Don't confuse it with the array solution in the other answer

Comment: Sorry i don't saw the before answer, that is more explicited